# How Do I Know the state is "Connecting" by InternetGetConnectedState

Tags: c#, connection, wifi, state

I'm creating an application that will connect to WiFi automatically when the connection state is unconnected.

I used the `wininet.dll` for it and to used its `InternetGetConnectedState()` method.

However, I've encountered a problem that whenever I connect to WiFi and the Connection State is "Connecting", the `InternetGetConnectedState()` will return false (meaning, unconnected), and it will try to connect to WiFi again and again...

This is the code:

```
while (true) {
    if (InternetGetConnectedState(out ConState,0))
    {
        (do something else)
    }
    else
    {
        (connect to wifi)
    }
}
```

Is there any other method available to know the `state` of connection or should i wait using the same method until the state is changed? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may have it wrong, but in the reference to the wininet.dll it's stated: "(InternetGetConnectedState) Returns TRUE if there is an **active modem or a LAN Internet connection**, or FALSE if there is no Internet connection", see [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702(v=vs.85).aspx). I think it's possible that this dll is not able to recognize the wifi network. Otherwise, the statement would have included "router" in it's explanation. You can call the GetLastError function to get additional information.

Answer (score 0):

[Network List Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370803(v=vs.85).aspx) gives all information about network states. You can take a look on its features using [this](http://www.btframework.com/NetworkListManager.zip) demo code (there is exe in Release folder).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer,but I Found that The States in NetWork List Manager  don't contain the state of "Connecting". Or maybe I don't find it yet?

Comment: For your task (detecting when internet connection available) you do not need this state. NLM provides the following state: Disconnected - no network connection; ipv4/ipv6 Internet - you have internet connection. Others - no internet but possible local connection. So once network status changed to ipv6/ipv4 Internet - you have internet connection. You do no tneed to call any other functions to detect when you have internet.